# reporting the spot its at c++

Tags: c++

I am trying to a program that gets the first, second, second to last and last position of a value

The way my program currently runs is it will cout the position of a value every time, rather than the ones I want.

```
//my code
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
  int number;
  int times;      
  int count=0;

  cout << "How many numbers will be entered?" << endl;
     cin >> times;
  do{

     cout << "Enter the number"<< endl;
     cin >> number;
     ++count;
      cout << count << endl;
     }

     while(times > count);

  if(number == 7 ){
     cout << "7 is in position: "<< count << endl;
     }
  return 0;
  }
```

Comment: You need a variable to store the count when the first `7` is observed and a second variable that is continuously updated each time a `7` is observed.

Comment: Whenever you're tracking something you need a variable or you need some way of computing it after the fact. You have neither here.

Comment: I don't believe that your program is printing the positions of all '7' ...

Comment: This sounds a bit academic... If this is related to school work you should verify that you're not violating any academic policies as well as state that in your question.

Comment: @JamesAdkison Thank you for your concern and yes it is related to school however I am not violating any policies and I will do that for now on

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to keep track of when the first and last 7 occur outside of your loop. One way is to store the location as they occur. Another would be to store all the input numbers and calculate the locations after they are entered. Here is an example:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main(){
    int number;
    int times;
    int count=0;
    int first = -1;
    int last = -1;

    cout << "How many numbers will be entered?" << endl;
    cin >> times;

    do {
         cout << "Enter the number"<< endl;
         cin >> number;
         ++count;

         if(number == 7) {
            if(first < 0)
                first = count;
            last = count;
         }
    }
    while(times > count);

    if(first >= 0) {
        cout << "The first 7 is in position: "<< first << endl;
        cout << "The last 7 is in position: "<< last << endl;
    }
    else {
        cout << "No 7 occurred." << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Edit:
When I solve these kinds of problems where I want a specific value or values, I usually first create variables prior to any other code in the function that will hold the value I want. In this case the goal is to have two numbers that I can access that represent the first time a `7` appeared and the last time a `7` appeared, so I created the `first` and `last` integer variables. 

The next thing I do is to set the variables to a value that is "invalid." That is, I want to be able to look at them at any point in the function and tell if one or more `7`s have appeared. By setting `first` and `last` to `-1`, I know that as long as they are set that way no `7` has appeared because if one had they would be updated to the minimum position of `1`.

Now I need to figure out where the best place to get the values I want are. The only time the code knows the value of the input and it's position is in your `do...while` loop after `++count`, so it seems like the best place to start. By adding the `if(number == 7)` I can define some code that will only execute if a `7` appeared. The next `if` checks if `first` has not been set, or in other words it is invalid because it is less than `0`. If this is the case, we know a `7` has appeared and that `first` should be updated. Finally, `last` will always be set because as far as we know the `7` that appeared may be the last one to appear.

The last change with the `cout`s has an `if` statement that checks if `first` is not invalid (is not -1). If that is the case, `first` has been set (a `7` has appeared), and thus `last` must have been set. If `first` was not set then no `7`s appeared.

Comment: This solves my problem that I was stuck on however I do not understand how, could you explain a little more of the logic of using int first and int last in the if statments

Answer (score 0):

The problem, as you've described, is that you only care about the *first* and *last* occurrence of `7`. When your application first starts `7` has never been entered and eventually data may be entered and the following outcomes are possible:

- `7` is never entered
- `7` is entered once (i.e., it will be the *first* and *last* occurrence)
- `7` is entered more than once (i.e., track the *first* occurrence and update the *last* occurrence for every subsequent `7`

#### Example Code

Also, see the code comments.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int firstPos = -1;
    int lastPos = -1;

    std::cout << "How many numbers will be entered? ";

    int numbersToEnterCount;
    std::cin >> numbersToEnterCount;

    for (int i = 0; i < numbersToEnterCount; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << "Enter num: ";

        int number;
        std::cin >> number;

        if (number == 7)
        {
            // This is true only when 7 has never been entered
            if (firstPos == -1)
            {
                // Set the first position, doing this will also prevent it
                // from being updated anymore
                firstPos = i + 1;
            }

            // Always update the last position
            lastPos = i + 1;
        }
    }

    if (firstPos != -1)
    {
        std::cout << "The first 7 was in position " << firstPos << "\n";
        std::cout << "The last 7 was in position " << lastPos << "\n";
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "7 was never entered\n";
    }

    return 0;
}
```